# Search a string for barcodes but ignore certain characters

Tags: strings, swift

I had to write a string search function that would search for barcodes, and be forgiving of minor formatting differences. For example, the barcode may be entered as `YF 1942-AB` in the customer's database, but a barcode scanner may read the barcode as `YF1942AB`.

The goal is to get the correct substring indices (range) for highlighting the text on an element, such as:

```
let text = "Serial: YF 1942-B (Scanned)"
let range = text.rangeOfStringWithIgnoredCharacterSet("YF1942B")
print(range) // (8, 16)
```

The approach I took was to do a regular string search but just ignore certain characters, and "sanitize" the search string before doing the search in earnest.

```
import Foundation

extension String {

    subscript (i: Int) -> Character {
        return self[self.startIndex.advancedBy(i)]
    }

    subscript (i: Int) -> String {
        return String(self[i] as Character)
    }

    subscript (r: Range<Int>) -> String {
        let start = startIndex.advancedBy(r.startIndex)
        let end = start.advancedBy(r.endIndex - r.startIndex)
        return self[Range(start ..< end)]
    }

    func rangeOfStringWithIgnoredCharacterSet(search: String, ignoredCharacterSet: NSCharacterSet = NSCharacterSet.alphanumericCharacterSet().invertedSet, options: NSStringCompareOptions = .CaseInsensitiveSearch) -> Range<String.Index>? {
        let newSearch = search.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(ignoredCharacterSet).joinWithSeparator("")
        if newSearch.isEmpty {
            return nil
        }
        var i = 0
        while i < self.characters.count {
            if newSearch.characters.count > self.characters.count - i {
                break
            }
            var startIndex = -1
            var endIndex = 0
            var j = 0
            while j < newSearch.characters.count {
                let k = i + j
                if k >= self.characters.count {
                    break
                }
                let c: String = self[k]
                if c.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(ignoredCharacterSet) != nil {
                    i += 1
                } else if c.compare(newSearch[j], options: options) == .OrderedSame {
                    if startIndex == -1 {
                        startIndex = k
                    }
                    endIndex = k
                    j += 1
                } else {
                    break
                }
            }
            if j == newSearch.characters.count && startIndex >= 0 {
                return self.startIndex.advancedBy(startIndex)...self.startIndex.advancedBy(endIndex)
            }
            i += 1
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

It all works properly, but it definitely feels a bit bolted together, since I'm using `Int` indices as well as dealing with `String.Index` types. I'd prefer to use `String.Index` exclusively, if possible, but Swift doesn't appear to have the equivalent of `std::iterator<T>::end` from the C++ STL, so I'm not sure if this is even possible.

Comment: I think there is a flaw in your code. It will not find `"ABC"` in `"AABC"`.

Comment: @MartinR Right you are, fixed.

Comment: Now it does not find `"aaabc"` in `"aaaaabc"`.

Comment: @MartinR Fixed now. I think living in high-level programming languages is making me rusty at the basics!

Answer (score 3):

***edit:*** The first time I read your code I mis-interpreted what was happening because of the signature of the function, and I suggested an approach that you were already using ¯_(ツ)_/¯

I like managing the loop using `String.Index` instead of `Int` because it saves a lot of casting you'd need to do otherwise (this is all in Swift 3).

```
let text = "hello"
var position = text.startIndex
while position < text.endIndex {
    let character = text[position] // get substring at range
    print(character)
    position = text.index(after: position) // increment index by 1
}
// -> prints
// h
// e
// l
// l
// o
```

Here's my approach that I hope gives you some inspiration or ideas!

***edit***: updated to loop over unicode scalars so it's easier to use `exclusions.contains(currentCharacter)`

```
extension String {

    func range(of target: String, ignoring exclusions: CharacterSet) -> Range<String.Index>? {

        var startPosition = unicodeScalars.startIndex

        let limit = unicodeScalars.index(unicodeScalars.endIndex, offsetBy: -target.unicodeScalars.count)

        while startPosition < limit {

            var targetPosition = target.unicodeScalars.startIndex
            var currentPosition = startPosition

            while currentPosition < unicodeScalars.endIndex  {

                // get characters at current & target positions then increment the current position
                let currentCharacter = unicodeScalars[currentPosition]
                let targetCharacter = target.unicodeScalars[targetPosition]

                print("target", targetCharacter, "current", currentCharacter)

                currentPosition = unicodeScalars.index(after: currentPosition)

                if currentCharacter == targetCharacter {
                    // if the current character matches the target character:
                    // - increment the target posistion
                    // - return the range if there are no more characters to match in the target
                    targetPosition = target.unicodeScalars.index(after: targetPosition)

                    if targetPosition == target.unicodeScalars.endIndex,
                        let start = startPosition.samePosition(in: self),
                        let end = currentPosition.samePosition(in: self) {

                        return start..<end
                    }
                }
                else if targetPosition == target.unicodeScalars.startIndex || !exclusions.contains(currentCharacter) {
                    // if:
                    // - we're still at the start of the target; or
                    // - the current chracter isn't one of our valid exclusion characters
                    // then:
                    // - advance the start position and break out of the loop
                    startPosition = unicodeScalars.index(after: currentPosition)
                    break
                }
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Testing

```
let messy = "Serial: YF 1942-B (Scanned)"

if let range = messy.range(of: "YF1942B", ignoring: CharacterSet.alphanumerics.inverted) {
    // -> Range<String.Index>(8, 17)

    messy.substring(with: range)
    // -> "YF 1942-B"
}
```